# How do I port a game made with Scratch, Pygame, or JavaScript to the Switch?

Tags: javascript, python, pygame, porting, nintendo

I've been making my own games in many different languages (mainly [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), [Python 3](https://www.python.org/) with [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/), and JavaScript), but, so far, *none* of them have been ported to the Nintendo Switch. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you signed up for the Nintendo Development Program?

Comment: I haven't really done that yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching for Scratch on Switch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=scratch%20game%20nintendo%20switch&ia=web) turns up this [this list of officially rejected suggestions](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/343602/):

> **2.7 Scratch for video game consoles**
>
> The Scratch Team does not have the resources to put a Scratch editor onto a video game console.  This includes making a Scratch editor for Nintendo Switch, 3DS, Xbox, and Playstation consoles.

[Searching JavaScript on Switch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript%20nintendo%20switch&ia=web) turns up [this way to access the web browser on the Switch](https://www.lifewire.com/access-nintendo-switch-web-browser-4583984) and point it to an existing web page with JavaScript on it. It might not support all JavaScript features your games use, mind.

[Searching for PyGame on Switch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pygame%20nintendo%20switch&ia=web) turns up this [guide to developing homebrew in Python](https://gbatemp.net/threads/nx-python-create-python-homebrew-for-the-switch.499150/) using [nx-python](https://nx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

When starting a new project, be sure to do these kinds of searches for yourself to get your initial leads, then ask here if you need help with a specific step along the way.